# is it possible to control the thread using python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to python and its libraries, I am currently working in multithreading. When I try to communicate between python and another simulation software I get some errors. may be trying to control the thread would help I think. Is there any way to activate a thread in which my function should run. To be more clear I want to command a function to run in thread1 and another function in thread5. How can be this done?

Comment: What did you try ? Did you looks for threads, multithreading on your favorite search engine ? Maybe give us an example (some code) to make it easier to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow carlos

yes, you can command a function to run in a thread and the other function in another thread.

simple example code should be like:

```
import threading
import time

def foo():
    print('foo function started')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('foo function finished')

def bar():
    print('bar function started')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('bar function finished')


x = threading.Thread(target=foo) # you can add args=() if you have function arguments
y = threading.Thread(target=bar)
x.start()
y.start()
```

I suggest you to read [this link](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) for more information